# OAuth Authentication for liferay JSON web services

Tags: web-services, authentication, oauth, liferay

I am using **Liferay 6.2 CE** & want to **authenticate** my **liferay web services** with **OAuth**. I have made a **remote json web service** in liferay in 'ServiceImpl' & its occurring in list of web services on page **http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws** & also working fine. But it works only when I am logged in the application on browser.
What i need is to authenticate all of them with OAuth, like hitting services from **Postman** etc, i have done this using **basic Auth**.
thanks